# Combining Schengen Visa Waiver and national visa — with a twist

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I’m in something of an unusual situation. At the end of the month, I’ll be traveling to Portugal, as a tourist, for about four weeks — before settling there for 6 months on a national visa.

Because the consulate has my passport for the national visa application, I requested a second valid passport, now in my possession.

My concern is that, because I will be entering with the second passport, without a visa, when I leave, I will appear to have overstayed the 90-Day schengen visa for American citizens.

Is this a potentially dangerous situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a day trip to UK or Morocco or non Schengen EU country and re enter with national visa?

Comment: I wondered about this — would that have me covered? So it would look like this? US --> PT (Schengen), PT--> UK (leave PT with Schengen, but enter Britain with national), UK--> Portugal (national), PT--> US (leave with national, but enter US with the passport I used for a Schengen)

Comment: PT -> UK using visa waiver, more like. Assuming you have a US passport, you don't need a visa to visit the UK.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, can you put your two comments together as an answer?

Comment: @Willeke it isn't an answer though. I don't actually *know* if he can enter Schengen on a 90 day waiver and transition to a national visa held in another passport while already in the zone. I just suggested an alternative which would make the point moot.

Comment: How and when will you get your passport after the visa is issued?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, I meant enter the U.K. on a visa waiver, but using the passport stamped with the national visa. As for the transition from Schengen to national visa, I know I can do so under EU 399/2016 Title 2 6.2. Whether or not that is complicated by the fact I’m using two passports, though, I don’t know. The U.K. plan seems like a good one.

Comment: @phoog i’ll have the passport securely sent to me. A relative is picking it up.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a potentially dangerous situation?

Yes.  The question is how great the potential for danger actually is, and I suspect it is quite small.

The Schengen codes say nothing to cause concern with your plan.  They simply say that periods of stay authorized under a long-stay visa are not considered for the 90/180-day calculation relevant to short-stay visas.

But national laws are also relevant.  If the Portuguese authorities are of the opinion that you must have an entry stamp on your D visa before your presence in Portugal can be considered "authorized" by that visa, there could be trouble.

The more general concern expressed in your question, that you might appear to have overstayed, is not particularly worrisome.  If anyone ever looks at your movements in and out of the area, you can use both passports to establish when you entered and left.  There's no requirement that an exit stamp be in the same passport as the entry stamp.  In fact, if you leave after being in the Schengen area for over 90 days, you may need to show both passports, since one has the entry stamp and the other has your visa.

To avoid the problem, you can travel out of the Schengen area after you get the passport with the visa, but before you have been there for 90 days.  When you leave, show the passport with the entry stamp, and when you return, show the passport with the visa.